# Jenkins - Multijob Phase marks build as failed when one of the step is not executed

Tags: jenkins

I am in need of little help here. appreciate any pointer on this issue.

One of my projects (MultiJob) has few phases (p1, p2, p3). I have set the conditions to proceed to each phase.

`Condition from P1 to P2 is only if P1 successful`

`Condition from P2 to P3 is only if P2 is Failed`

Everything would be fine except in a case where P2 succeeds. Whenever P2 succeeds, P3 does not run (this is what I want) but it marks Jenkins job as UNSTABLE.

Am I missing something here? Is this is the right approach to handle the cases I have? Please suggest

Comment: This is what I see in my Job's console `Build step 'MultiJob Phase' marked build as failure`

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional build step plugin : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin

[image: image attached with an example]

Comment: I can't use conditional build step as my other subsequent phases depend on this phase. Is it not possible to stop the phase marking build as failed when it is not run?

Comment: With conditional build plugin you can trigger the dependent builds as well..This requirement can be satisfied with conditional build plugin "Condition from P2 to P3 is only if P2 is Failed" .. As well as first .

Comment: I have a huge list of jobs to run and many of these get triggered in parallel. So I would need to stick to MultiJob phase projects only. My question is can this be done in MultiJob phase project

Comment: check this : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin  see this : "Since version 1.11:

1. control build success criteria based on job status:"